# Excel CSV files delimiter change

Tags: excel, vba, csv, powershell, delimiter

I'm creating in Excel a sub-folder in a directory and save there multiple CSV-files from a Excel Workbook

My problem is that I need to do this on a system where the list separator is a ','. The CSV files are getting read from a system where the default list separator is a ';'. I cannot change this

So I need to change the ',' in the CSV files into a ';'. My idea is to achieve this using PowerShell.

My first attempt was to change the delimiter of the CSV immediately after creating it in excel by passing to a script the file-name. I manage to change the delimiter for a certain file but I struggle to pass the pathname to the script (no error but also no change in the file):

Script Code:

```
param([string]$path)
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path) #readParameter

Import-CSV -Path $content  -Delimiter ','|Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv  -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation #Export a CSV-File with ;
(Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file -FilePath C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv -Force -Encoding ascii #remove " from file
Remove-Item -Path $content #remove old CSV-file
Rename-Item -Path C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv -NewName $content #change file name
```

Excel Call:

```
Call Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Users\Desktop\delimiterChange.ps1 -path """ & location & """", 1)
```

Thank You

Comment: If you turn on Excel Macro recording, then import a CSV using Data/From Text and use the import wizard. You can then define the delimiter which will be recorded as a macro. Use the basis of this to import the remaining files in a VBA routine. This will avoid having to change regional delimiter settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
param([string]$path)
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($path) #readParameter

Import-CSV -Path $content  -Delimiter ','|Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv  -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Your code reads the *content* of the CSV (assuming that the path to the CSV is passed via the parameter `-Path`) and tries to pass that as the *path* to `Import-Csv`. Change the above to this:

```
param([string]$path)

Import-CSV -Path $path |
   Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\Desktop\temp.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

You can even replace the content of the file if you run `Import-Csv` in an expression:

```
(Import-Csv -Path $path) |
   Export-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

I'd recommend keeping the double quotes, but if you must remove them you can do that in the pipeline like this:

```
(Import-Csv -Path $path) |
   ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoType |
   % { $_ -replace '"', '' } |
   Set-Content -Path $path
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PS, this is the easy quick and dirty. Works like a charm.

```
$csv = Import-csv "C:\initial.csv"
$csv | Export-Csv "C:\converted.csv" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Control Panel* > *Regional Settings* > *Additional Settings*

Set the *List Separator* to the **semi-colon**:

[image]

Then, in Excel SaveAs **CSV**

Comment: this works but I don't want to change the setting all the time

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach.

In a Macro enabled Excel workbook:

1) Create a routine which will import a semi-colon-delimited file. It should take a filename as a parameter and return a workbook.

2) Create a routine which will export a workbook as a CSV. It should take a workbook as a parameter, a file name as a parameter, and export/close the workbook

3) Create a routine which reads a file list from the directory and then runs 1) and 2) on each file.

Additionally, I would not name the semi-colon delimited files CSV if you have any control over the original file names. By definition, CSV means Comma Separated Values. Name them something else. Then your routine only has to find the semi-colon files and can skip the CSVs because those have already been converted to comma separated.